# Practical way to combine conflicting options

Tags: algorithm, list, logic, combinations

I have a script which accepts multiple options as arguments. The list of valid options may be large (>20) which could result with conflicts. Is there a practical way to combine the conflicted ones together, and non-conflicted into another without creating multiple lists, groups, etc. Changes to one group will result in changes to other groups.

For example, the list of available options:`-a, -b, -c, -d`

The following options conflict: `[-a, -c], [-a, -d]`

The following options don't conflict: `[-a, -b], [-c, -d]`

EDIT, A more precise example:

For example, the script allows to start/stop a specific task and has additional options for creating/deleting logs.

A normal start would look like :
`./script -start Task -logFile C:\out.tmp`

And the script should notify the user in case something like: 
`./script -start Task -stop Task` is executed, since `start` and `stop` are two opposite actions.

Another conflicting action: 
`./sript -start Task -logFile C:\out.tmp -deleteLog C:\out.tmp` , which would create a log file and delete it at the same time

Now, if the options are `start, stop, logFile, deleteLog`,

The following would be conflicting: `[start, stop], [logFile, deleteLog]`

The following would not be conflicting: `[start, logFile], [stop, deleteLog]`

Comment: Could you be more precise as to what the input is and what the expected output is? Can you give a complete example?

Comment: I would blindly parse options into a configuration dictionary, and then set variables internally based what is in that configuration.  While setting variables I'd scatter checks for conflicts, check whether files exist, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that, as you are writing the source, you can decide how to organize your arguments for parsing time. For example (using JSON notation, you can easily adapt this to C structs, Java enums or what-have-you), you can annotate the available options to explicitly indicate *which* of them conflict:

```
const options = [
  {
    name: "start",
    description: "starts foobaring the fizzbuzz",
    parameters: [
      { 
        name: "task",
        type: "string",
        optional: false,
        description: "the type of task to foobar"
      }
    ]
    conflicts: ["stop"] // <-- explicit simple conflict detection
  },
  { ... }
]
```

This would be used by a command-line parsing module to

- generate a nice help screen, possibly including conflicting options
- return a map of command-line options, say `parsedArgs`, so that `parsedArgs['start']` would correspond to the parameters of the `start` parameter if it was specified.
- detect simple conflicts, by complaining if conflicting options are detected at parse-time.

Note that there may be additional conflicts that it may not be worthwhile to detect at the parsing stage. For instance, if the value of option `foo` must be larger than `bar` + `baz`, it is better to code a check for this fact after parsing, rather than complicating the parser to handle arbitrary relationships between option values.